# Clear a QGraphicsScene from an event of one of the items

Tags: python, pyside

I have a QGraphicsScene with many QGraphicsItem. Some items have buttons that clear and repaint the scene.

> The problem is that the clear() method deletes the QButton (and its
>   associated data structures) in the middle of a method call that uses
>   those very data structures. Then, immediately after clear() returns,
>   the calling method tries to access the now-deleted data (because it
>   wasn't expecting to be deleted in the middle of its routine), and bang
>   -- a crash. From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20387679/clear-widget-in-a-qgraphicsscene-crash).

I found the solution for C ++ [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20387679/clear-widget-in-a-qgraphicsscene-crash), however I am using PySide and could not use the same solution for python.

Follow my code:

```
class GraphicsComponentButtonItem(QtGui.QGraphicsItem):

    def __init__(self, x, y, update_out):
        super(GraphicsComponentButtonItem, self).__init__()

        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.update_out = update_out

        self.setPos(x, y)

        self.createButton()
        self.proxy = QtGui.QGraphicsProxyWidget(self)
        self.proxy.setWidget(self.button)

    def boundingRect(self):
        return QtCore.QRectF(self.x, self.y, self.button.width(), self.button.height())

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
        # Paint same stuffs

    def createButton(self):
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton()
        self.button.setText('Clear')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.action_press)

    def action_press(self):
        # Run some things
        self.update_out()


class QGraphicsViewButtons(QtGui.QGraphicsView):

    def __init__(self, scene, parent=None):
        QtGui.QGraphicsView.__init__(self, parent)
        self.scene = scene

    # It's called outside
    def updateScene(self):
        self.scene.clear()
        self.scene.addItem(GraphicsComponentButtonItem(0, 0, self.updateScene))
        self.scene.addItem(GraphicsComponentButtonItem(0, 50, self.updateScene))
        self.scene.addItem(GraphicsComponentButtonItem(0, 100, self.updateScene))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the conversion of the following C++ code:

```
QObject::connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), scene, SLOT(clear()), Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

to python is:

```
self.button.clicked.connect(self.scene().clear, QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection)
```